# What reason to specify InitialHeapSize more than 1m?

Tags: java, heap-memory

I understand why to specify MaxHeapSize - it is upper limit which can be allocated by JVM.

Is there any reason to specify InitialHeapSize more than, say 1m (or even 1k)?
Anyway once an application allocated that memory amount JVM will extend it.

Answer (score 5):

You are right that the size will be extended until the maximum is reached by allocating more memory. Reallocating takes some time, so setting the initial size avoids that the VM has to reallocate too often. If you know how much your application will typically need, then setting the initial size can increase performance.